# use lambda to access ec2 without access key and secret python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I am able to access s3 and dynamoDB from a lambda function without using access key and secret using boto3 python. But when I do the same for ec2 instance its not allowing me. Throwing the following error:

```
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  17,
  "lambda_handler",
  "'Arn': ec2Arn"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py",
  520,
  "do_action",
  "response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py",
  83,
  "__call__",
  "response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
  159,
  "_api_call",
  "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
  494,
  "_make_api_call",
  "raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)"
]
],
"errorType": "ClientError",
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: SOME RANDOM STRINGS"}
```

The code I used in the lambda function is:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    import boto3
    ec2Arn="EC2_ARN_WITH_INSTANCE_PROFILE"
    bdm=[{"DeviceName": "/dev/sda1","Ebs" : { "DeleteOnTermination": True}}]
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")
    instances = ec2.create_instances(ImageId="AMI_ID",
                                 KeyName="KEYNAME",
                                 MinCount=1,
                                 MaxCount =1,
                                 InstanceType="m3.medium",
                                 SecurityGroups=[security],
                                 BlockDeviceMappings=bdm,
                                 InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior="terminate",
                                 IamInstanceProfile={
                                   'Arn': ec2Arn
                                   })

    return "Done"
```

But when I try to invoke s3 or dynamoDB it executes successfully. I wanna access ec2 that way too so that I wont unnecessarily hard code access key and secret.

Thank You.

**UPDATE**: I understood why. The arn I am passing to the ec2 is not authorised to be used by the lambda function. If I run the lambda function without passing the instance profile, I am able to launch the instance.

But I dont understand how to do that? Should I edit some role to add a policy for the lambda function? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You should have an IAM role assigned to the Lambda function. You need to edit that role to add the required permissions.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for that. Exactly what I needed..